# Python Script for Duplicate Subnets

Tags: python, excel

I am having excel which contain list of subnets (2000+).Now  I need to read the subnets from excel,find out overlapping subnets and put those overlapping subnets in different excel.I need to achieve this using python script. Please help me in getting the output .

Please find the sample excel below.

```
S.no  | Location |    Subnet
------  ---------  -----------
 1    |     A    |  10.20.30.0/24
 2    |     B    |  10.21.30.0/16
 3    |     C    |  120.0.0.0/8
 4    |     D    |  10.20.30.0/8
 5    |     E    |  100.50.40.0/24
 6    |     F    |  24.30.40.0/28
```

Comment: Care to show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

hint 1: Convert each (start) IP address into a single number

```
A = 1st octet * 2^24
  + 2nd octet * 2^16
  + 3rd octet * 2^8
  + 4th octet
```

hint 2: calculate an end address from mask

the segment contains `x = 2^(32-Mask)` addresses, therefore your end address is

```
B = A + x -1
```

finding out if any range (Ax, Bx) overlaps range (A1, B1) becomes trivial then, you need a loop comparing each range to all the ones following.